A Conjectured Formula for the Average Gap Between Twin Primes Below $10^{N}$
I noticed a pattern in the average gap between consecutive twin primes less than $10^N$. Here's the formula.
Average gap between consecutive twin primes =
$\begin{cases} 
(2N - 1)^2 + 1, & \text{for } N \leq 6, \\
(2N - 1)^2 + (N - 6), & \text{for } N \geq 7.
\end{cases}
$
Observations

I have verified the formula for $N = 1$ to $N=10$ using Python.
The growth of the average gap follows a quadratic pattern for $N \leq 6$ and introduces a linear correction term for $N \geq 7$.

Example Calculations

For $N = 3, 10^3 = 1000$,
the predicted average gap is:
$
  (2 \times 3 - 1)^2 + 1 = 5^2 + 1 = 26 \approx 25.82
  $

For $N = 7, 10^7 = 10,000,000$,
the predicted average gap is:
$
  (2 \times 7 - 1)^2 + (7 - 6) = 13^2 + 1 = 170 \approx 169.55
  $


Request for Insights

Empirical Verification: Has anyone extended this verification for $N > 10$? I am not able to calculate beyond $10^{10}$.
Theoretical Proof: Can this formula be derived?

Computational Challenges
For $N \geq 10$, direct computation becomes infeasible due to memory and processing constraints. I utilized a segmented sieve and twin prime generation in Python for lower $N$, but higher ranges require distributed computing or advanced optimization techniques.
Can the average gap between twin primes be formally expressed as a function of the density of twin primes? Does this formula have any connection to the Hardy-Littlewood conjecture for prime pairs?

Example Code for Verification
Here’s Python code using sympy for computing twin primes in a given range, which I used to verify the conjecture:

def simple_sieve(limit):
    """ Find primes up to a given limit using a basic sieve """
    sieve = [True] * (limit + 1)
    sieve[0] = sieve[1] = False
    primes = []
    for p in range(2, limit + 1):
        if sieve[p]:
            primes.append(p)
            for i in range(p * p, limit + 1, p):
                sieve[i] = False
    return primes

def segmented_sieve(limit):
    """ Efficient segmented sieve for large limit """
    sqrt_limit = int(math.sqrt(limit)) + 1
    primes = simple_sieve(sqrt_limit)
    
    low = sqrt_limit
    high = limit
    sieve = [True] * (high - low + 1)
    
    for prime in primes:
        start = max(prime * prime, (low + prime - 1) // prime * prime)
        for j in range(start, high + 1, prime):
            sieve[j - low] = False
    
    return primes + [i + low for i in range(high - low + 1) if sieve[i]]

def find_twin_primes(limit):
    """ Identify twin primes less than limit """
    primes = segmented_sieve(limit)
    twin_primes = []
    for i in range(1, len(primes)):
        if primes[i] - primes[i - 1] == 2:
            twin_primes.append((primes[i - 1], primes[i]))
    return twin_primes

def average_gap_between_twin_primes(limit):
    twin_primes = find_twin_primes(limit)
    if len(twin_primes) < 2:
        return 0
    gaps = [twin_primes[i + 1][0] - twin_primes[i][0] for i in range(len(twin_primes) - 1)]
    return sum(gaps)/len(gaps)

# Example: Test for a smaller limit, like 10^8
N = 7  # For limit 10^8
limit = 10**N
avg_gap = average_gap_between_twin_primes(limit)
print(f"Average gap between twin primes less than {limit}: {avg_gap}")



$10$ is a bit of a "magic number" here so, even if the asymptotic relationship is $O(N^2)$, which it may well be, there is no reason to expect the leading term to be exactly $4N^2$. Looking at OEIS A007508 up to $N=18$, it is plausibly marginally higher for large $N$.
This is related to the first Hardy–Littlewood conjecture and the twin prime constant $\Pi_2 \approx 0.6601618158468695739278$ and where the number of twin prime pairs below $x$ may be $$\pi_2(x) \approx 2\Pi_2\frac{x}{(\log_e(x))^2}$$ and if so $$\frac{10^N}{\pi_2(10^N)} \approx \frac{(\log_e(10))^2}{2\Pi_2 }N^2\approx 4.0156N^2$$ while your expression suggests something nearer (and below) $4N^2$.

You’re right that $10$ is somewhat arbitrary and $4N^{2}$ may not be exact—it’s just what I observed for $N≤9$. The connection to the Hardy-Littlewood conjecture and
$Π_{2}$  makes sense, and I see how the asymptotic gap could scale closer to $4.0156N^{2}$.
It’s possible my conjecture underestimates the average gap slightly due to the local distribution of twin primes in the tested ranges.
